# Uninstall/Remove Firefox Extension programmatically?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a way to uninstall Firefox extension programmatically. If yes - Is it possible to execute this script from some other extension ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Get a reference to the add-on using [`AddonManager.getAddonByID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#getAddonByID%28%29)
2. Check that the add-on can be uninstalled (e.g. system-wide add-ons cannot be uninstalled by the user normally, but can be disabled), by checking the `PERM_CAN_UNINSTALL` flag.
3. Call [`Addon.uninstall()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Addon#uninstall%28%29).

Example code (you might want to add proper error handling, and so on):

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.getAddonByID("some@id", function(addon) {
  if (!addon) {
    // Add-on not present
    return;
  }
  if (!(addon.permissions & AddonManager.PERM_CAN_UNINSTALL)) {
    // Add-on cannot be uninstalled
    return;
  }
  addon.uninstall();
  if (addon.pendingOperations & AddonManager.PENDING_UNINSTALL) {
    // Need to restart to finish the uninstall.
    // Might ask the user to do just that. Or not ask and just do.
    // Or just wait until the browser is restarted by the user.
  }
});
```

Comment: For what reason could an add-on not allow uninstalling? In that case can uninstall be forced?

Comment: The addon can e.g. be installed system-wide and the user running the Firefox instance does not have write permissions to the install location. You cannot force a uninstall then (lacking write permissions). But you can disable such by setting `Addon.userDisabled = true`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to remove an extension programmatically: you can [remove the xpi files from the firefox profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cannot-remove-add-on-extension-or-theme#w_uninstalling-manually):

- Windows:

> '%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\extensions\extension@name.xpi

- Linux/Mac:

> /home/*/.mozilla/firefox/extensions/extension@name.xpi

Answer (score 0):

From a security standpoint, the only thing that would make sense is if an extension could remove itself. Even though the question states how to do this from another extension, I think for the sake of completeness, it is important to add how an extension can remove itself.

This can be done using [management.uninstallSelf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management/uninstallSelf).

```js
browser.management.uninstallSelf({ 
  showConfirmDialog: true, 
  dialogMessage: 'Please reconsider, since this is the best extension!' 
}).then(() => alert('Extension uninstalled'))
  .catch(() => alert('User cancelled extension uninstall'))
```

If `showConfirmDiloag` is true, the user is prompted with a confirmation dialog.

If the user chooses to keep the extension, the Promise returned by uninstallSelf returns an error.

Both properties in the argument object are optional.